# Mvn Connection Timeout Error because of proxy Setting in Redhat 7 while connecting via Bamboo

Tags: networking, proxy, maven-3, redhat, bamboo

My Bamboo agent is trying to get a Mvn pom file from the repo on a virtual machine and I am getting Connection Timeout. The OS I am using is RedHat7. 
I have my proxy settings as follows

~/.bashrc - both for user and root

```
    export proxy=http://username:password@proxy.XXX.com:8080/
    export http_proxy=$proxy
    export https_proxy=$proxy
    export HTTP_PROXY=$proxy
    export HTTPS_PROXY=$proxy
```

The Maven settings file  settings.xml:

```
  <proxy>
          <id>optional</id>
          <active>true</active>
          <protocol>http</protocol>
          <username>username</username>
          <password>passsword</password>
          <host>proxy.XXX.com</host>
          <port>8080</port>
          <nonProxyHosts>local.net|some.host.com</nonProxyHosts>
    </proxy>
```

In my yum.conf I have also added the proxy settings, although it is not reuired

```
proxy=http://proxy.XXX.com
proxy_usename=username
proxy_password=password
```

Also my in my /etc/sysconfig/network

```
NETWORKING=yes
NETWORKING_IPV6=no
IPV6_AUTOCONF=no
HOSTNAME="XXXXXX.co.XXXX.com"
NOZEROCONF=yes
GATEWAY=XX.XX.XX.X
```

I can do wget and but when the bamboo tries to download a pom.xml it gives the following error:

```
https\://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/.error=Could not transfer artifact io.spring.platform\:platform-bom\:pom\:1.0.2.RELEASE from/to central (https\://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2)\: Connect to repo.maven.apache.org\:443 [repo.maven.apache.org/23.235.40.215] failed\: Connection timed out
```

What am I missing? Is there another configuration that needs to be set ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So the issue was with the repository. It required to be pointed to the Nexus repository